# reusing returned values from functions

Tags: python, function, return

I am trying to figure out how to reuse a value I have returned to my function.
for this example a = 0, b= 0, c = 5:

```
def helllo_wolrd(a,b,c):
    import random
    for elem in (a,b,c):
        if elem == 0:
            print ('trying again')
        if elem is not 0:
            return elem
```

now lets say I would like to continue the function like this:

```
value = random.randint(1,elem)
```

or just use a for loop to go through that range mentioned above.
How do I call that elem that was returned and then re use it?
Same question for re using the elem in a separate function. Or in other words,How do I call a returned value from within a function to be used in a second function.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

In your example `elem` is equal to 5, and you can assign the return value to a variable like this:

```
new_variable = helllo_wolrd(0,0,5)
```

Now `new_variable` is equal to 5 as well. Then you can use the new variable in other expressions.

```
value = random.randint(1,new_variable)
```

Answer (score 1):

If all 3 values `a,b,c` are 0 your function will `return None` implicitly. Your random call would throw an Error. You can supply a default value in case `elem` is None:

```
elem = hello_world(0,0,0)
value = random.randint(1,elem or 42) # uses 42 if elem is None (or 0)
```

if not all three are 0, elem can be used as is without defaulting to something.